# Flask's flash function does not work when called inside a flask-meld component

Tags: python, flask, backend, flask-socketio

I have a `meld component` and the flask's `flash` function does not work after form submission inside my registration page, everything's fine and working and I think it's because of context issues but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Here is my flask app structure:

```
app-name
- app-name
    - meld
        - components
            - registration_form.py
    - static
    - templates
        - meld
            - registration_form.html
        - user
            - register.html
        - layout.html
    - __init__.py
    - config.py
    - extensions.py
```

My meld component (`registration_form.py`)

```py
class RegistrationForm(Component):
    form = Form()
    submitted = False

    def updated(self, field):
        self.validate(field)
        self.submitted = False

    def save(self):
        self.submitted = True
        if self.validate():
            form = self.form
            #generate hashed password for the password
            hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
            
            user = User(
                    first_name=form.first_name.data,
                    last_name=form.last_name.data,
                    username=form.username.data,
                    email=form.email.data,
                    password=hashed_password
                )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Your account has been created!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('user.login'))
```

My meld template:

```html
{% from "components/fields.html" import field %}

<div>
    <h1 class="text-center">Welcome!</h1>
    <p class="title text-center">Please sign up to continue</p>
    <div class="input-container">
        <form meld:submit.prevent id="registerForm" action="" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

            {{field('first_name', fa_icon='user', form=form)}}
            {# ... fields here #}

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4 login_container">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-grad",
                    **{"meld:click": "save()",
                        "meld:loading.attr": "disabled",
                        "meld:loading.class": "opacity-80 cursor-not-allowed"}) }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My registration page template

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% meld "registration_form" %}
{% endblock %}
```

User.login page

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form id="loginForm" action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <!-- PASSWORD -->
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <!-- SUBMIT -->
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Layout file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    {% block style %}{% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% meld_scripts %}

    <div class="container">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for category, message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif%}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    
    <!--Bootstrap JavaScript-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your user.login template look like?

Comment: updated my post to include the templates